# Does Swagger really support SOAP services?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

Swagger seems like a lovely UI for viewing web service contract. I was particularly excited to learn that it "happily speaks both JSON and XML". After spending some hours learning about it I got to a road block.

SOAP contract is XML based but how exactly do I make Swagger display my SOAP service contract?
Are there sample Swagger implementation of XML based support?

Comment: It is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777601/can-swagger-be-used-for-soap/25779296#25779296 You can check out my answer there.

Comment: @Santanu Dey, I don't think an old question can be a duplicate of a newly asked question

Comment: Good point. Did not realize this is the original question. Thanks for pointing out. I hope the answer was still relevant for you.

Comment: Did you find a SOAP-Swagger integration mechanism at all?

Comment: Have you found something like Swagger for soap? I need to get the UI for the service and also mock the responses. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Answer:** SOAP services are not supported by Swagger UI.

Popularity of SOAP has waned a bit and there seems to be no appetite for a swagger UI for SOAP services.

Comment: It has, but some vendors like Siemens are deploying it in new products in 2018.