# Swagger support for thrift?

Tags: swagger, thrift

I used Swagger in the past for Java REST API and it was the best available tool for the purpose.

Does swagger support generating documentation for Thrift RPC files?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer No - Swagger doesn't support thrift.

This is closest to swagger, which fortunately is supported out of box for thrift

This command generates HTML documentation for the given thrift file.

```
thrift -r --gen html  your-thrift.thrift
```

Also while digging for this found that you can generate automatic diagram of the data structure defined in thrift file

```
thrift -r --gen gv your-thrift.thrift
dot -Tpdf -o your-thrift.pdf gen-gv/your-thrift.gv
```

Answer (score 1):

> Thrift RPC files

Thrifts basic document is the Thrift IDL, or **interface description language**.

This IDL describes the API in an high-level manner and at the same time serves as the input to generate code required for the langauge bindings.

To achieve that, an Thrift IDL file contains not only declarations, but also is allowed to use bot normal comments and so-called "doc comments" in it. Many lanaguge bindings support direct conversion from doc-comments into the langauge specific form, hence the documentation will also find its way into the generated code.

There is a [good example for documentation inside a Thrift IDL file](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/DocTest.thrift) in the source tree. Additionally, consider using the GraphViz generator (`-gen gv`) to get graphical documentation for your IDL or the HTML generator (`-gen html`), or the (rather old) XSD generator.

Swagger (or Apiary) offer an UI-type interactive way to play with the implementation. This is something where there is no equivalent in Thrift today.

> Does swagger support generating documentation for Thrift [...] files?

Swagger deals with RESTful services. Thrift is an RPC system and the two have some conceptual differences. Hence, it is very unlikely that swagger will ever come to a point where it will be capable of documenting anything besides REST.

Related question: [Can Swagger be used for SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777601/can-swagger-be-used-for-soap)